# Live Streaming a Live Event

Tags: video, streaming, video-production, live-streaming

***TLDR:** What do I need to do to set up a decent quality live stream of a live event? I'm talking gear, setup, the whole thing.*

I'm no stranger to video production but I'm getting an increased amount of requests for live streaming events (both within the company I work for and externally) and I'm not 100% sure of the best way to go about setting this up. I'm going to try and break down a few of the assumptions and questions I've got in the hopes that someone will be able to answer them for me.

The most common request I have is:

> "Can we Live Stream this event that we're hosting for people who can't attend?"

Obviously the answer is "Yes - how much do you want to spend?" so let's assume that they don't want to spend much and I've not got a huge pot of money to buy new kit.

AFAIK I'll need: a camera to film the event (could be as simple as a webcam but I've got a DSLR that I'd like to use), some way of capturing sound (events typically have presenters that are miked up so perhaps I can pull audio off the mixer?), a laptop to run the A/V feed through (possibly a capture card or some sort of switcher, too?), streaming software (I'm thinking OBS or similar) and finally the stream provider (Zoom, for example).

Here're the questions:

- What else do I need to consider?
- Do I need a capture card or can I just run HDMI from the camera?
- How do I get live sound from the mixer without compromising the live event?
- Do I run the sound via the camera or via a recorder to the laptop?
- Do I need an external switcher or will OBS software solution do the job just fine?

Thank you in advance, sorry this is a bit of a beast of a question!